# How to access subquery in main selection and join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I am new to SQL, so I decided to mess around with the Northwind database. I am currently trying to show information about the employees, specifically how much money each one has obtained from all of their orders. This is what I currently have to get the total money from each EmployeeID:

```
SELECT Orders.EmployeeID, SUM(cost.Total) AS TotalSales
FROM Orders, (
SELECT OrderID, SUM(OrderDetails.UnitPrice * OrderDetails.Quantity) AS Total
FROM OrderDetails
GROUP BY OrderID
) AS cost
GROUP BY Orders.EmployeeID;
```

This works fine, however I am having trouble adding this subquery to the rest of the selection:

```
SELECT Employees.EmployeeID AS ID, Employees.LastName AS Last, Employees.FirstName AS First, Employees.Title, COUNT(EmployeeTerritories.TerritoryID) AS `Number of Territories`
FROM Employees
LEFT JOIN EmployeeTerritories ON Employees.EmployeeID = EmployeeTerritories.EmployeeID
GROUP BY Employees.EmployeeID;
```

I've tried this:

```
SELECT Employees.EmployeeID, Employees.LastName, Employees.FirstName, sales.TotalSales
FROM Employees, (
SELECT Orders.EmployeeID, SUM(cost.Total) AS TotalSales
FROM Orders, (
SELECT OrderID, SUM(OrderDetails.UnitPrice * OrderDetails.Quantity) AS Total
FROM OrderDetails
GROUP BY OrderID
) AS cost
GROUP BY Orders.EmployeeID
) AS sales
LEFT JOIN sales ON Employees.EmployeeID = sales.EmployeeID
GROUP BY EmployeeID;
```

However, I get an error saying that the table 'northwind.sales' doesn't exist. I think I understand that this is because it only exists where it was declared, but I'm not sure how to work around this.

How can I add this subquery so that it works with JOIN, and I can have a TotalSales column? Is this even possible, or is creating a new table the only way I can do this?

Comment: Yes, it is in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your queries and later it's earier to combine them. The first one can be done by a simple `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT o.EmployeeID, SUM(od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) AS TotalSales
FROM Orders as o
join OrderDetails as od
    on od.[OrderID] = o.[OrderID]
GROUP BY o.EmployeeID;

select
    *
from (SELECT o.EmployeeID, SUM(od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) AS TotalSales
FROM Orders as o
join OrderDetails as od
    on od.[OrderID] = o.[OrderID]
GROUP BY o.EmployeeID
        ) as sales
join (SELECT Employees.EmployeeID AS ID, Employees.LastName AS Last, Employees.FirstName AS First, Employees.Title, COUNT(EmployeeTerritories.TerritoryID) AS NumberOfTerritories
FROM Employees
LEFT JOIN EmployeeTerritories ON Employees.EmployeeID = EmployeeTerritories.EmployeeID
GROUP BY Employees.EmployeeID, Employees.FirstName, Employees.LastName, Employees.Title
        ) as employlees
    on sales.EmployeeID = employlees.ID
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to remove the brackets in order for it to work. The only thing is that there are two columns for ID, and I want to move TotalSales, but I should be able to work it out from here.